# Flash Photo Uploader - Take photo from web cam

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, upload, file-upload

Are there any examples of Flash + Javascript libraries which allow you to display a variable-sized Flash movie in your page that captures Webcam snapshots (still frames), and submits them to your server in a JPEG format?

Currently I know of: [jpegcam](http://code.google.com/p/jpegcam/)

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Webcam Snapper**

- JavaScript API, or HTML tag
- JPEG and PNG output
- Optional filters & photo effects
- Adjustable size, zoom, countdown, flip

http://www.webcamsnapper.com/

It has both free and paid versions.

Comment: sweet - this is nice quality.

Answer (score 4):

**Webcam snapshot example :**

http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=189240

**Jpeg encoding Class:**

http://code.google.com/p/as3corelib/source/browse/trunk/src/com/adobe/images/JPGEncoder.as

**Jpeg encoding + Saving on server tutorial :**

http://designreviver.com/tutorials/actionscript-3-jpeg-encoder-revealed-saving-images-from-flash/

Comment: Theo- thank you. I don't have flash and would not be able to develop a component that would allow me to take a screenshot so I was looking for an already made component like jpegcam.

Comment: Hang on, so you're not looking for a library but actually for an existing application ? FYI, in case you are programmer you can still develop this with free tools (Flex SDK + Flash Develop/Text Mate/etc.)