# webcamcapture + photoupload (like Facebook) for PHP

Tags: php, flash, webcam

On my PHP-based (Joomla!) site users should be able to provide a photo of themselfes and provide some comments to it (e.g. Name). This file along with the comment should then be stored on the server. The user should simply be able to do this either by uploading a file or by taking a picture with their webcam directly on my site. I like the way Facebook has solved the user interface for that. Is there a free (or cheap) component (I suppose it needs to be done with flash?) that I can intergrate into my PHP site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there are any free and useful webcam applets out there. I ended up writing my own. Getting an image from a webcam is not really hard in flash. I then use PNGEncoder (com.adobe.images.PNGEncoder) from adobe itself to convert the bitmap data into a PNG images (by default flash does bitmaps only and those are way to big to upload). I end up with an URLLoader to post it to my site.

I got some wisdom from this url: http://marstonstudio.com/?p=36

Comment: Can the upload and storage be fully done in flash/actionscript? No php involved?

Comment: Also what is the lowest version of flash I can do this with?

Comment: You need something on the server end that will take the uploaded file and put it where it belongs. The applet just emulates a POST (like when you would upload a file manually). You can use the same page for both manual and webcam upload. The code I referred you to is AS3, so the lowest version that can compile that, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

- [jpegcam](http://code.google.com/p/jpegcam/)
- [webcamsnapper](http://www.webcamsnapper.com)

similar question
[Flash Photo Uploader - Take photo from web cam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2492582/flash-photo-uploader-take-photo-from-web-cam)