# How can I add webcam capabilities to my site?

Tags: php, flash, webcam, video-capture

I'm trying to allow users to take pictures with their webcams and save it. How can this be done? I am looking for something similar to Facebook or dailybooth in terms of their UI. I know smoe PHP/jQuery but I'm also wondering how I could save the pictures once "taken"?

Comment: i think php jquery can help you only in uploading pics!!

Comment: HTML/CSS/JS have no concept of webcams, but Flash does. If the user allows it, you can have a flash applet capture a picture from the webcam then use regular AS3 scripting to upload the capture to your server.

Comment: possible duplicate of [webcamcapture + photoupload (like Facebook) for PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359736/webcamcapture-photoupload-like-facebook-for-php)

Comment: HTML does have a concept of webcams, just not implemented yet :) http://blog.whatwg.org/whats-next-in-html-episode-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Facebook webcam thing is made using flash as you can see here:

[image]

This is all pretty easy to achieve with Flash (the actual capturing of what the webcam can see). I'm not sure how developers get from there to uploading the image to a server, though.

If you have knowledge in Flash / ActionScript 3, then this will get you started:

[Camera.getCamera()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Camera.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6#getCamera%28%29)